# MySQL "SELECT DISTINCT" Efficiency for very large tables

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a very large table (millions of records) containing approximately 8 fields as a primary key. for simplicities sake lets say that the table looks like this:

```
    key_1 | key_2 | key_3 | ... | key_8 | value
```

given a value for key_1, I need to fetch all possible values for key_2, key_3, ..., key_8
something along the following lines:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT key_2 FROM table1 WHERE key_1 = 123;
    SELECT DISTINCT key_3 FROM table1 WHERE key_1 = 123;
    ...
    SELECT DISTINCT key_8 FROM table1 WHERE key_1 = 123;
```

My problem is that this query is significantly slower then my performance needs, and the data in this table is fairly constant and rarely updated(once every few days). Also table_1 could be a slow sub-query. Short of creating an additional table in the database and manually updating it every time the database is updated, is there another solution that can give me fast results. I would need it to work across multiple MySQL Sessions.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to create that additional table and update it every time the data changes.

Comment: Create a diffrent Index on a column used in key.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Can't give a definitive answer with the information we have, but let's start with these:

#### Do you have an index on key_1?

Without it, each query by itself will already be slow just looking for 123.

#### Do you have an index on (key_1, key_2)?

Because `select distinct key_2 where key_1 = 123` is really fast if it can get all the necessary data from the index alone. No need to access the table.

#### Are the rows/indexes fixed-size?

Traversing a fixed-size table/row can be faster because one always knows where the x-th record is by just calculating the offset. Variable row sized tables are slower.

#### Have you tried adding an autoincrement surrogate primary key?

Indexes work way better when all they have to store is the column, and a small primary key. Composite primary keys are slower.

#### Did you consider a read-only table?

You can pack myisam table for fast access, but they become read-only. It's a hack that has its uses though.

#### One step further, have you considered a datawarehouse?

If the tables don't change often, it might be best to duplicate the information for fast access.

Can you post a `show create table` statement? Seeing the columns and indexes would help.
Can you post an `explain select` statement? Seeing which indexes are used would help.

Comment: Unfortunately due to my companies policy, I cant post the create table statement. That being said, there are no indexes in the table except for the primary key across all the fields.

Comment: No indexes? Your EXPLAIN SELECT will probably be hurting then. I suppose you can't make a copy of the table and rename the columns, just for us to work with?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT DISTINCT key_2 FROM table1 WHERE key_1 = 123;
```

This can use your primary key index (key_1, key_2, etc.) It will perform an index scan, which is faster than a table scan or a temporary table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT key_3 FROM table1 WHERE key_1 = 123;
```

Cannot use the primary key because the combination of key_1 and key_3 don't form a prefix for the primary key. You need to create a compound index on key_1 and key_3, in that order. Then, it can use that index to perform an index scan also.

```
SELECT DISTINCT key_8 FROM table1 WHERE key_1 = 123;
```

Needs index on key_1 and key_8, in that order. Same as above.